# Get all posts by a group of users ordered by timestamp

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three models: a User, a Post, and a Follow, which records when a user followed another user.  I want to show all the posts by users that the current user follows.  The list of posts should be ordered by timestamp.  However, the list seems to be grouped by user id, then ordered by timestamp.  How can I get all the posts by the followed users ordered only by timestamp?

```
followed_users = Follow.query.filter_by(follower_id=current_user.id).all()
followed_posts = []
for i in followed_users:
    followed_posts.extend(Post.query.filter(Post.author == i.followed_id).order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).all())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You queried for all the users, then for each user you queried for their posts ordered by timestamp.  The final result is a list of posts ordered by timestamp, grouped by user.  Instead, query all the posts by any of the users.  Pass the query for all the followed ids to the query for any posts by any of those ids.

```
followed_ids = db.session.query(Follow.followed_id).filter(Follow.follower_id == current_user.id).subquery()
followed_posts = Post.query.filter(Post.author.in_(followed_ids)).order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).all()
```